# AWS Lambda boto3 : Instance launch from lambda boto3 python but not launching

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, python, aws-cli, amazon-lambda

while trying launch instance from python function instance not launching but not getting python syntax error.

````
region = 'us-east-2'
ec2 = boto3.client('ec2')
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')
client = boto3.client('ec2')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
     response = client.describe_images(
    Filters=[
        {
            'Name': 'description',
            'Values': [
                'lambdaami',
            ]
        },
    ],
    Owners=[
        'self'
    ]
)
     AMI = sorted(response['Images'], key=lambda x: x['CreationDate'], reverse=True)
     print AMI[0]['ImageId']
     INSTANCE = ec2.create_instance(ImageId='ImageId', InstanceType='t2.micro', MinCount=1, MaxCount=1)
     print (INSTANCE[0].id)```



Kindly help.....
````

Answer (score 2):

I have solved this issue by help the community here is the code.

````
import boto3

ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2', region_name='us-east-2')


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    images = ec2.images.filter(
        Filters=[
            {
                'Name': 'description',
                'Values': [
                    'lambdaami',
                ]
            },
        ],
        Owners=[
            'self'
        ])

    AMI = sorted(images, key=lambda x: x.creation_date, reverse=True)
    IMAGEID = AMI[0].image_id

    INSTANCE = ec2.create_instances(ImageId=IMAGEID, InstanceType='t2.micro', MinCount=1, MaxCount=1)
    print(INSTANCE[0].image_id)```
````